# findAllByX incorrectly limited to 10 results

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In Spring Data Elasticsearch - I noticed something that looks like a bug with the generated `findAllByFoo` type methods.
These seem to be **limited to the default size (of *10*)** - which goes against the semantics you would expect from a `findAll` operation.

The main `findAll()` operation does work correctly however and does return all documents.

So - is this a bug or is there something I'm missing?
Cheers, 
Eugen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like a bug.

According to elasticsearch's documentation ([from/size](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)) it looks like 10 is the default number of results that elasticsearch will return from a search query.

You can modify the page size with an appropriate Pageable parameter, e.g.:

```java
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20))
```

Comment: That makes sense - and that's how I was working around it. However, this is a findAll operation, so my thinking is that, when I look at that API, I expect ALL entities to be returned. So basically I expect Spring Data to generate a query that will do that. But - if there's nothing I'm missing, than that's that :) Thanks.

Comment: @Eugen The way I see it, it would make sense for a "findAll" operation to return every record in the context of a database, but since Elasticsearch is operating in a search context, it simply means "search without criteria" and is subject to the same default result limit as any other search.

Comment: Well, sure, but considering that the main usecase here is storage, and the whole point is using elasticsearch as a storage system not only (or not primarily) for search - I'd much rather have it behave as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ElasicsearchTemplate` to search through multiple nodes and provide the number of pageRequest (or results) you want. The default is 10.

```java
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;    

public List<MyElasticDocument> getData() {

    String textToSearch = "John";

    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(
                    QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(textToSearch)
                            .lenient(true)
                            .field("jsonNode1")
            )
            .should(
                    QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(textToSearch + "*")
                            .lenient(true)
                            .field("jsonNode2")
                            .field("jsonNode3")
            );

    NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(query)
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 20)) // provide the no. of results you want
            .build();

    List<MyElasticDocument> elasticDocumentList = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(build, MyElasticDocument.class)

    return elasticDocumentList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-58 it works as designed and is not subject to change. Read the comments in this issue to understand the performance background.